# Convert simple function to multithread one

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following function which I would like to transform in a multi-threading one:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import json


def url_searcher(value):
    url_file_path = "C:\\Users\\Link\\Desktop\\"

    for filename in os.listdir(url_file_path):
        if filename == "url_list.json":
            with open(url_file_path + filename) as f:
                for line in f:
                    returnJson = json.loads(line)
                    if value in returnJson["url"]:
                        return returnJson


print(url_searcher("http://zadkay.com/blog/wwp/51065983.jpg"))
```

Basically, it is going to search in a `JSON file` for a value. The main problem is that the file is big (more than 50mb) and I need results as fast as possible (more than 7 seconds are considered too much).

This is an extract from the file so you can see the structure:

```
{"dateadded": "2019-11-04 12:33:27", "url_status": "online", "tags": "elf", "url": "http://2.56.8.16/bins/arm7", "reporter": "Gandylyan1", "threat": "malware_download", "id": "251402"}
{"dateadded": "2019-11-04 12:33:25", "url_status": "online", "tags": "elf", "url": "http://2.56.8.16/bins/arm6", "reporter": "Gandylyan1", "threat": "malware_download", "id": "251401"}
```

**Question:**

What are the steps? Is it a good idea and will this improve the speed of getting a result?

Here you can see a `JSON` example of the file with more lines: https://pastebin.com/MXYTg1CV

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should work with text without converting from JSON to Python structure. If url is alway in the same place then you could slice it and check if value is in this part of text.

Comment: mayb it will work faster if  you simply use `if value in line:`

Comment: I have to use JSON because the same function will apply to different structure. Key,Value is what I need here, also because of the return which must be a json.

Comment: you can convert JSON string to dictionary after you find value in text

Comment: ok, but what about multi-threading ? is a good idea with the actual code ?

Comment: can you transform the data into a more appropriate data structure first?  e.g. a dictionary keyed by the `url`, or a database with an appropriate index

Comment: Python needs some time to create `thread`, and `threads` may not work at the same time in Python. Maybe [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) would work better. So you would have to try to see if it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

First, measure, not guess.
Get acquainted with snakeviz:
https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/

```
pip install snakeviz
python -m cProfile -o program.prof my_program.py
snakeviz program.prof
```

On my machine 65% of the time is spent in `decode` function from `decoder.py` from json library.

Let's try a simple improvement:

```
with open(url_file_path + filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        # returnJson = json.loads(line)
        # if value in returnJson["url"]:
        #     return returnJson
        if value in line:
            returnJson = json.loads(line)
            return returnJson
```

On my machine, I see 10x improvement of execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a thread in python is really easy

```py
import threading

thread_one= threading.Thread(name='searcher', target=url_searcher, args=(value))                
thread_one.start()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

But I think this will not reduce the processing time, it will only allow you to read several files at once and may even take longer to process each file.

The structure of the file is always the same?
Have you tried processing it as a plain text file and searching for the key name?

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty much like an I/O limited operation:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from __future__ import print_function
from functools import partial
import json
import glob


def url_searcher(pathlist, value):

    for filename in pathlist:

         with open(filename) as f:

            for line in f:

                returnJson = json.loads(line)

                if value in returnJson["url"]:

                    return returnJson

no_of_threads = 4 #can be set manually or allocated automatically by Pool (see docs)

url_file_path = "C:\\Users\\Link\\Desktop\\"
value = "very_important_stuff" #adjust to your liking!

workers = Pool(no_of_threads)

pathlist = [f for f in glob.iglob(url_file_path, recursive=recurse) if "url_list.json" in f]

result = workers.map(partial(url_searcher, value = value), pathlist)

workers.close()       
workers.join()
```